# How do you use justify-content-around with Bootstrap 4 navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to figure out how to properly align navbar items in bootstrap 4. I can get the result to look correct, but doing so only with the "wrong" markup. I'd like the 5 items within the navbar to be evenly distributed across the navbar.

Example here: https://www.bootply.com/ggqjNmuq9H

Answer (score 2):

`justify-content-around` only affects direct children, so you should put it on your `<ul>`. Make sure your `<ul>` also has `w-100` to make width 100% or you won't see any spacing.